# Why do some cargo aircraft have windows?

Tags: windows, cargo

There are some cargo aircraft that have windows which are not covered. Look:
[image]

On the second deck above where it says "Hong Kong Asia's World City" the aircraft has 3 uncovered windows. Source: [Airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Cathay-Pacific-Airways/Boeing-747-867F-SCD/2345584/L/)
Also here:
[image]

Source: [Airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Martinair-Cargo/Boeing-747-412%28BCF%29/2774380/&sid=0fbb5f03d1b747884d20748ce994c767)

On the upper deck of the Martinair 747 the windows are not covered. My question is: if the aircraft is used for cargo, why do they leave the windows uncovered?

Comment: There is still a crew that goes with the flight, including a load officer and possibly a relief crew.

Comment: I see a bird strike in the top image.

Comment: Both aircraft in your pictures are 747's. It's not really feasible to load cargo in the upper deck. The most comfortable jumpsuit I ever had on a FedEx freighter was the old 747-200 we had which was a converted passenger plane. The upper deck still had the first class seats installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some cargo aircraft do have limited seating, as mentioned in the comments it could be for the relief crew, load officer, or other employees making a hop on the plane. Here is a nice [blog post about  flying in a cargo plane](http://josefindsaway.com/2014/09/03/flying-in-style-the-centurion-cargo-way/). [This article covers it pretty well also](http://www.nycaviation.com/2015/02/anatomy-freighter/#.Vt2tlJMrKV4).

[image]
([source](http://josefindsaway.com/2014/09/03/flying-in-style-the-centurion-cargo-way/))

Some cargo planes are also old passenger planes and some of the windows may be left in place.

Comment: > "Some cargo planes are also old passenger planes and some of the windows may be left in place. " - you can see in the OP's second picture that all of the windows in the lower deck and some of the ones on the upper deck have been painted over.